# Windows Azure Virtual Network Point-to-Site: This connection requires security features that are not available on this platform

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect a Windows 10 Enterprise client machine to a point-to-site Azure VPN service using the AzureVPN  executable downloaded from the portal:

> This connection requires security features that are not available on this platform. For information, contact customer support.

Logs are:

```
    Operating System      : Windows NT 10.0 
    Dialer Version        : 7.2.19041.572
    Connection Name       : [redacted]
    All Users/Single User : Single User
    Start Date/Time       : 1/02/2021, 14:05:20
******************************************************************
    Module Name, Time, Log ID, Log Item Name, Other Info
    For Connection Type, 0=dial-up, 1=VPN, 2=VPN over dial-up
******************************************************************
[cmdial32]  14:05:20    03  Pre-Init Event  CallingProcess = C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasautou.exe
[cmdial32]  14:05:29    04  Pre-Connect Event   ConnectionType = 1
[cmdial32]  14:05:29    06  Pre-Tunnel Event    UserName = [redacted] Domain =  DUNSetting = 773c0063-700a-4c7e-8979-804be09e3acb Tunnel DeviceName =  TunnelAddress = [redacted]
[cmdial32]  14:05:31    21  On-Error Event  ErrorCode = 13 ErrorSource = RAS
```

Anyone ever seen anything like this before and have an idea about exactly what security features might be missing on the client? Or could it be related to setup in Azure?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use a client of OS Windows NT 10.0 ? See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/work-remotely-support#p2s) for the supported client OS and authentication method with P2S VPN.

Comment: @NancyXiong thanks for the suggestion and the link. Went through and tried a couple of tweaks in the article but no joy! Your comment did prompt me to add a bit more detail to the description though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters this the solution is to enable push notifications as your preferred 2FA method here:

https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/proofup.aspx?proofup=1

It appears that the Azure VPN app doesn't support 2FA codes hence the

> security features that are not available on this platform

error message